# Translate virtual address to physical from multi-level pagetabels

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-address-space

I'm trying to convert an virtual memory address to a physical one, but can't get it to work. I'm currently doing an operating system as an assignment, and now I have to implement a printf function for the usermode, so when you invoke the write syscall the system should print the content of the array in usermode to the serial port(for now), and to do that i have to convert the address from virtual to physical.

Here is my code from the syscall handler:

```c
Pcb* pcb = getCR3(); // contains the page directory for usermode
setCR3(kernelPageDir); // set the CR3 register to the kernel page directory

uint32_t tableNum = (vAddr >> 22) & 0x3ffUL; // get the upper 10 bits
uint32_t pageIndex = (vAddr >> 12) & 0x3ffUL // get the middle 10 bits
uint32_t offset = vAddr & 0xfffUL; // get the 12 lower bits

uint32_t* topTable = pcb->pageDirectory[tableNum]; // Access the top level table
uint32_t lowTable = topTable[pageIndex]; // Entry to the 2nd table
uint32_t* addr = lowTable + offset; // Should be the physical address

serialPrintf("Structure: tableNum=%08x pageIndex=%08x  offset=%08x\n", tableNum, pageIndex, offset);
serialPrintf("Address: topTable=%08x lowTable=%08x addr=%08x\n",topTable, lowTable, addr);
serialPrintf("Char:%c", (char*)addr[0]);
```

When I run the code, it gives me a page fault when trying to access the value of it:

```
Structure: tableNum=00000020 pageIndex=00000048  offset=00000378
Address: topTable=00000000 lowTable=0015d000 addr=0015d378
Page fault! errcode=00000000 addr=0015d378
```

Here is the part from the book that explains the structure of the pages:

[image: Structure of the page table levels]

Comment: (Assuming your other code is correct...) you cannot *use* (i.e. dereference) a physical address directly in accessing memory. The physical address is only used by the hardware itself. All code (even kernel mode code) uses virtual addresses to access memory. There is no way to get around it. Now, assuming the data page is present, accessing the actual data would be done with `*((char *)vAddr)` (although in practice kernel code only accesses user virtual addresses through specific functions that ensure user-mode addressing limits are respected, and page faults are properly handled and so forth).

Comment: 1. How do you get kernel pgd address? It is stored in init_mm structure. I hope you would have taken care of this.
2. Since it is a syscall handler, I hope this code is running in kernel space.
3. You can not dereference the physical addresses directly in kernel. Instead you have to do kmap() on every table traversal and use that VA to traverse the next table entry.
Above all, I do not see any compulsion of page table traversal for your usecase. You can directly use *((char *)vAddr) (typecast it based on the argument passed to your custom printf) to print the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you fill out a pte for the last (index 1023) entry in the second level table which is pointed to by the last (index 1023) of the first level table, then:

```
0xfffff000 .. 0xfffffffc will by an alias of the first level table,
```

and

```
0xffc00000 .. 0xffffffff will be an alias of the entire (sparse) page table.
```

For example:

```
int vtop(unsigned vaddr, unsigned *pa) {
    unsigned *pdtb = (unsigned *)0xfffff000;
    unsigned *pte = (unsigned *)0xffc00000;
    if (ptdb[vaddr>>20] & 1) {
         if (pte[vaddr>>12] & 1) {
              *pa = pte[vaddr>>12] &~0xfff;
              return 0;
         }
         return 2;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

You can do this for any index and adjust the pointer values, but if gets more confusing, and 0xffc/20 is out of the way.